# Дискуссия между пользователями в блоке на Мете

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-так-задумано

Зашёл сейчас по адресу http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com, справа увидел вот такое:

[image: Дискуссия Утки]

Раньше не доводилось замечать, чтобы ссылка на дискуссию между двумя пользователями находилась на заглавной странице Меты. Не уверен, что так должно быть; возможно, это дефект.

Comment: дискуссия - это обычный чат с таким названием, поэтому все нормально, там показываются то ли активные чаты, то ли последние

Comment: А мне кажется, групповые чаты на заглавной уместнее, чем дискуссия между двумя пользователями.

Comment: Так я как раз и говорю, что **нет разницы** между этими двумя комнатами.

Answer (score 8):

В блок "N человек общаются" попадают два самых активных в последнее время чата, относящихся к текущему сайту.

Два вышеуказанных чата совершенно равнозначны для системы. Приватные чаты здесь отсутствуют, а все обычные считаются равноправными. Не вижу ничего плохого в возможности других участников зайти и присоединиться к обсуждению.

Название "Дискуссия..." было выбрано создателем комнаты чата самостоятельно. Он с тем же успехом мог выбрать "Сверхсекретная комната только для своих, никому не входить!", но комната осталась бы публичной.

Comment: В следующий раз так и назову =D